# Virgin Atlantic - Approved COVID-19 Test Centres

Tags: covid-19, london, virgin-atlantic

Has anyone recently (within the past 3 months) travelled with Virgin Atlantic (United Kingdom) with their negative PCR test? If so, could you kindly share the details of where you have found this information?

We need to travel for some family emergency and are discovering that there is a huge inconsistency between what is mentioned in Virgin Atlantic website and what happens during departure day. Several folks have been denied boarding. It'd be good to know from someone who's done this.

Regards,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.